# List items created through Javascript are not aligning properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need to display video and when user presses menu, I need to divide the screen to 2 halves vertically (adjacent to each other) and I need to display a text in middle (horizontally and vertically) of first half and need to display a list in the second half (this list also should be in middle of 2nd half horizontally and vertically). I created a parent div and 2 child divs with flex and adding list items dynamically through javascript. Code is as given below.

```js
function displayMenu() {
  var mid = document.getElementById('mid');

  if (mid.classList.contains('hidden') == false) {
    mid.classList.toggle("hidden");
    return;
  }

  var ulid = document.getElementById('ulid');

  for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    let lItem = document.createElement('li');
    lItem.style.width = '100%';
    lItem.style.height = '150px';
    lItem.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    lItem.style.borderWidth = '1px';

    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "img/TNT.png";
    lItem.appendChild(img);
    lItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('FIRST'));
    ulid.appendChild(lItem);
  }

  mid.classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function changeChannel(e) {
  console.log('received keyEvent : ' + e.keyCode);
  let keyCode = e.keyCode;

  if (keyCode == 77) {
    displayMenu();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', changeChannel);

displayMenu();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src='js/index.js'>
  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%
    }
    
    #vid {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: -1;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    #mid {
      opacity: 0.5;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vmin;
      justify-content: stretch;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    
    #mid.hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #mid1,
    #mid2 {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #mid1 {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
    
    #mid2 {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    }
    
    #ulid {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <video id='vid' src='textMotion.mp4' autoplay loop></video>
  <div id='mid' class='hidden'>
    <div id='mid1'>
      <h1>TEXT</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='mid2'>
      <ul id='ulid'></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I am facing multiple issues when I ran this as below.

1. The whole list is not centered vertically and horizontally in the second half.
2. The list Item is not starting from starting of second half.
3. Image on the list is not getting displayed from left of the list.
4. Text on the item is not getting displayed in the center of the list vertically.

Screen shot is as below.

[image]

Can any one please help me to fix these issues?

Comment: It sounds like this issue might not have anything to do with JavaScript. I think you first need to figure out the HTML that produces the layout you want and _then_ create the JavaScript to generate it. So this question can be simplified to an HTML+CSS question.

Comment: Can you create an example image of what you are expecting the output to be? This can/might help clear up any misunderstanding of your expectations.

Comment: @NewToJS: It is simple. The list items should start from left of 2nd half. TNT image should be at the starting of the list Item. 'First' string should be in the center of the list item instead of at the bottom.

Comment: I still think an image might help clear up your expectations. I have no idea what you mean by *"The list items should start from left of 2nd half."* left of 2nd half? 2nd half of what? *"TNT image should be at the starting of the list Item"* Do you mean aligned to the left? I could lead to more questions but to avoid that a image of your expectations could avoid this.

Comment: @NewToJS: I am not sure how to create an image with my expectations. That was the reason I am trying to explain. If you observe the attached image, there are 2 boxes. One box is having text. Another box is having list items. But the list's left position should start with second half. But I think it is starting after some 20 pixels. TNT image should be aligned to the left of list item.

Comment: And list as a whole should vertically in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it is a little hard to know exactly what you want without an image.  But I think this might be moving things in the right direction.

The fixes are as follows
1. add a class to the list item and give it flex properties that make it left-justified (`justify-content: flex-start`) and vertically centered (`align-items: center`).
2. update the flex properties for the `#mid1` and `#mid2` elements and `align-self` on `#mid1` to get the text centered in that box.

CSS changes

```
.list-item { 
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#mid1,
#mid2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
}

#mid1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  align-self: center;
}
```

Javascript changes

```
for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
  let lItem = document.createElement('li');
  lItem.style.width = '100%';
  lItem.style.height = '150px';
  lItem.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  lItem.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  lItem.classList.add( "list-item" ); // Add a list-item class

  ...
 }
```

You can see the results here https://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/vjobQp.  I grabbed a TNT image from Google as a placeholder.

Hope this helps